# Is my Hadoop Data File System okay with an Incorrect configuration message?

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to install hadoop on my own laptop for study purposes with [the tutorial from tutorialspoint.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hbase/hbase_installation.htm) I launched `start-dfs.sh`:

The expected output was:

```
10/24/14 21:37:56
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop-
2.4.1/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-localhost.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop-
2.4.1/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-localhost.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
```

But I get:

```
mike@mike-thinks:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ ./start-dfs.sh 
Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
Starting namenodes on []
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access '/usr/local/hadoop/logs': No such file or directory
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-mike-namenode-mike-thinks.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-mike-namenode-mike-thinks.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open '/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-mike-namenode-mike-thinks.out' for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-mike-namenode-mike-thinks.out: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-mike-namenode-mike-thinks.out: No such file or directory
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access '/usr/local/hadoop/logs': No such file or directory
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-mike-datanode-mike-thinks.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-mike-datanode-mike-thinks.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open '/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-mike-datanode-mike-thinks.out' for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-mike-datanode-mike-thinks.out: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-mike-datanode-mike-thinks.out: No such file or directory
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
The authenticity of host '0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:/s7X8QMliB6FVx5bde5AaCycprQ/B+NtcTXrInrXxJM.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? no
0.0.0.0: Host key verification failed.
```

So I tried with the `sudo` command:

```
mike@mike-thinks:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ sudo ./start-dfs.sh 
Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
Starting namenodes on []
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-root-namenode-mike-thinks.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-root-datanode-mike-thinks.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
The authenticity of host '0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:/s7X8QMliB6FVx5bde5AaCycprQ/B+NtcTXrInrXxJM.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
0.0.0.0: Warning: Permanently added '0.0.0.0' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-root-secondarynamenode-mike-thinks.out
```

The incorrect configuration left me puzzled ...

I then tried to launch yarn:

```
mike@mike-thinks:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ sudo ./start-yarn.sh 
[sudo] password for mike: 
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-root-resourcemanager-mike-thinks.out
nice: ‘/usr/local/hadoop/bin/yarn’: Permission denied
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-root-nodemanager-mike-thinks.out
localhost: nice: ‘/usr/local/hadoop/bin/yarn’: Permission denied
```

I did a `chmod +x` on `yarn`

```
mike@mike-thinks:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ sudo ./start-yarn.sh 
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-root-resourcemanager-mike-thinks.out
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-root-nodemanager-mike-thinks.out
```

But I wasn't able to access `http://localhost:50070`

I retried and I now have to run against my deamons:

```
mike@mike-thinks:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ sudo ./start-yarn.sh 
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-root-resourcemanager-mike-thinks.out
localhost: nodemanager running as process 8183. Stop it first.
mike@mike-thinks:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ sudo kill 8183
mike@mike-thinks:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ sudo ./start-yarn.sh 
starting yarn daemons
resourcemanager running as process 9513. Stop it first.
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-root-nodemanager-mike-thinks.out
mike@mike-thinks:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ sudo kill 9513
mike@mike-thinks:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ sudo ./start-yarn.sh 
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-root-resourcemanager-mike-thinks.out
localhost: nodemanager running as process 10058. Stop it first.
```

Yet I'm able to reach "Hadoop All applications" page on `http://localhost:8088/`:

[image: Hadoop All applications page]

Answer (score 0):

I (archlinux user) had the same problem in Hadoop 3.0.0. But I know some consideration of it.

So, Please try

1. run jps command and check the existence of "NameNode"
   if you couldn't find NameNode, you should redo your Hadoop.
2. run telnet localhost 8088/50070 command and check connection
   I cannot connect 50070 port, but can connect 8088 port... (I couldn't find this solution)